# Can I configure FileZilla server so that it only writes the file once upload is complete?

Tags: filezilla, ftp

Can I configure FileZilla server so that it only writes the file once upload is complete?

I have a PowerShell script watching a directory for processing, so I'd prefer that the file didn't appear until the upload was complete - presumably FileZilla would write the file to a temporary directory until it was complete.

Answer (score 2):

How about having your script upload and then rename the file when finished. Have your mnitor only look for specific filenames or patterns. Or upload to a temp directory and then move to the monitored directory.

Answer (score 1):

How about having a trigger file added to the queue that starts further processing of your bigger file once it got uploaded?